# How to pass regular expression extracted value in json format for PUT call in jmeter?

Tags: testing, jmeter

I am testing RESTapi with (json format) using (HTTP Request sampler) in jmeter. I am facing problems with the PUT calls for update operation.
The PUT call with parameters don't work at all using (HTTP Request sampler), so now i am using the post body to pass the Json.

How can i pass the extracted values from the previous response to next PUT request in thread group? Passing the 'Regex veritable' to PUT call in Post body don't work, it doesn't take ${value} in Post body.

How do i carry out UPDATE operations using (HTTP Request sampler) in Jmeter?

Comment: Any feedback on this answer ?

Answer (score 2):

Check that your regexp extractor really worked using a debug sampler to show extracted value.
Check your regexp extractor is scoped correctly.

See this configuration:

A Variable:

[image]

Its use with a PUT request:

[image]

The sampler result:

[image]

Comment: yes..! regexp extractor works fine with debug sampler, it shows extracted value properly. problem is to pass extracted value ${value} in post body in Json format for PUT call